# Were there ever plans for a TNG movie with Q as the main antagonist?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-q, star-trek-movies

Q is arguably the greatest antagonist in *TNG*; we see him in the first and last episodes of the series and he frequently pops in.

If we think about *TOS*, arguably the greatest antagonist there was Khan, who later was the main antagonist in *Wrath of Khan*.

So, based on this observation, my question is **were there ever any plans for Q to be the main antagonist in a *TNG* movie?**

Comment: http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Undeveloped_Star_Trek_projects

Comment: Antagonist? Q single-handedly saves the Federation from the Borg, prevents Picard from destroying the galaxy and then helps Janeway crap all over the Borg's transwarp hub, preventing the deaths of trillions. Aside from his slightly odd manner, he's history's greatest hero.

Comment: The problem with Q is that he's basically nigh-omnipotent, and so a hypothetical movie in which he is a bonafide villain would last all of five minutes, and that's if Q plays around a little. The entire Federation vanishes with a snap of Q's fingers. Worf would probably be first to go.

Comment: @T-1000'sSon Good point! I've taken the liberty of adding that to my answer. N_Soong: does my answer give you what you were looking for? :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Probably not ...

[This link](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Undeveloped_Star_Trek_projects) (found by @Richard) gives you a list of planned Star Trek film projects that never came to fruition, and none of them seems to feature Q.

The more interesting question, I think for you is well, is **why not?** And we have an answer to this question from the guy who knows Q better than anyone!

### ... because he's not enough of a 'villain'.

There's an interview with Q's actor John de Lancie [here](http://trekmovie.com/2010/07/26/john-de-lancie-on-why-we-havent-and-wont-see-q-in-a-star-trek-movie/), in which he explains why, in his opinion, he never made it into a Star Trek film and probably won't either:

> StarTrek.com has a fan Q&A with John de Lancie where he responds to various questions about his career on and off Trek. Regarding why he never appeared in one of the four Next Gen movies, de Lancie spoke of the nature of how Q is not really a bad guy:
>
> > **Q was never a villain as far as I was concerned, and the films needed villains.** I might have been arrogant and badly flawed and all that, but I never thought of the character as a villain. And **I don’t think, after a while, that the writers and producers thought of me as a villain.** If they’d used me in one of the films in the way they’d used me in some of the episodes I just mentioned, sure, that would have been great. But I don’t think that’s what they needed.
>
> de Lancie also explained why (even though he would be interested) he doesn’t expect to appear in the new universe of the JJ Abrams Star Trek films :
>
> > I’d be very interested. The only problem is that I, too, am suffering from this mortal thing called aging and there’s a point at which it might not make sense. What might make sense is that you hear my voice, but **I just don’t know that it would make sense to have an aging Q. I would have a problem with that as a viewer, and I don’t think I’d be the only one.**

(all emphasis mine)

As @T-1000'sSon mentioned in a comment on the question, another good point is that if he *was* a real villain, intent on the Federation's (or humanity's) destruction rather than just toying with them, he's so powerful he could destroy the lot in an instant. It wouldn't be much of a film, unless he was somehow handicapped and less powerful than he's seemed so far, which doesn't seem too believable.

Comment: For the record, he *was* the guest star in the show's "feature-length" final episode.

Comment: @Richard True (and also in the double-length Encounter at Farpoint?), but doesn't really address N_Soong's question...

Comment: Indeed, hence why I posted it as a comment.